# Activate swap by default

Tags: 11.04, 12.10, partitioning, swap

I installed Ubuntu 11.04 Natty and I set a partition for swap about 900 MB. Afterthat, I installed Kubuntu 12.10 Quantal, repartitioned my hard disk so I had 2048 MB swap (replaced 900 MB swap partition).

I ran Kubuntu, and it's ok. But after I ran Ubuntu 11.04 Natty, It didn't use that swap. But I can activate it with Gparted.

Some additional information.
When I installed Kubuntu Quantal. I make 256 MB partition (ext4 mount point in /boot) which replaced previous 256 MB partition (ext4 mount point in /boot) that I created when I installed Natty.

Something wrong with my configuration?.

Answer (score 0):

Try running `sudo swapon -a` 
If it your swap partition doesn't start, then you'll have to add it to your fstab. There will probably be an old entry for a SWAP partition, you can go ahead and comment that out and use it as a template for your new entry.